# Issue`The format string "{f. ̃}{vv ̃}{ll}{, jj}" has an illegal brace-level-1 letter` with IEEEtran

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

With the bibliography style IEEEtran.bst, bibtex produces a lot of messages starting with

```
The format string "{f. ̃}{vv ̃}{ll}{, jj}" has an illegal brace-level-1 letter
```

For example having in the bibtex file:

```
@inproceedings{cn18,
    author = {Smith, John}
}
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Can you share some code with a bib entry that produces that error please? I just went through `bibtex` and `IEETran` bibtex on CTAN and cannot find either the format string or the error message in either

Comment: The tildes look wrong: According to https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html?%7Bf.%20%CC%83%7D%7Bvv%20%CC%83%7D%7Bll%7D%7B,%20jj%7D they are `U+0303 COMBINING TILDE`, but they should be `~` (`U+007e TILDE`). I have no idea what happened to your file, though, because the original `IEEEtran.bst` on CTAN (http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran.bst) has the correct `~`. ...

Comment: ... How did you install your TeX system? How did you install `IEEEtran.bst`? Did you (or anyone else) manually modify the file? Do you have a local copy of `IEEEtran.bst` or a local copy of the whole `IEEEtran` somewhere? Have you tried re-installing the `IEEEtran` package?

Comment: @JamesT added bib code

Comment: @moewe I have installed TexLive through `apt` on Debian 11 and the same for IEEEtran.bst (in the package `texlive-publishers` [https://packages.debian.org/stable/tex/texlive-publishers])

Comment: And you are sure there is no other `IEEEtran.bst` on your system? You only have the one installed by `apt`? Can you try re-installing the `texlive-publishers` package? Can you open `IEEEtran.bst` and find out if the tildes inside are the correct `U+007e` tildes or combining tildes (`U+0303`)? (You can run `kpsewhich IEEEtran.bst` in the command line to find out where the file is.)

Comment: @moewe I'd just installed `IEEEtran.bst` (through `apt`) since otherwise that file was not found by bibtex to compile my `bib` file, so it is the unique. And the tildes inside it are indeed `U+007e`

Comment: @moewe solved, thanks! I was using `@IEEEtranBSTCTL` inside the `bib` file, where the tildes were the wrong ones.

Comment: Please write up a quick answer below and accept it. That way you help future visitors with a similar question and mark the question as resolved.

Comment: @moewe As you prefer (I was waiting, since the actual answer is due/thanks to you!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using `@IEEEtranBSTCTL` inside the bib file, with an entry

`CTLname_format_string = "{f. ̃}{vv ̃}{ll}{, jj}",`,

where the tildes were the wrong ones (see first comment by @moewe to the question), probably after copying it from some pdf file (maybe the one of IEEEtran documentation).

Solution was replacing combining tildes  `̃` by tildes `~`.